# @ key not working in eclipse (Windows XP)

Tags: eclipse, windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

The keyboard combination <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> = @ (german keyboard) is not working in eclipse but everywhere else. I'm using windows XP. It is not a language problem, I have already deinstalled the english keyboard and all other charactes work perfectly fine.

It's also kind of impossible to google this, because the character is escaped by the search engine and all other people seem to have the language problem.
The problem is very annoying because I need to use annotations a lot, so hints how to solve this would be greatly appreciated ;-)

Comment: Not that it would've helped you, but this happened to me by accident because I happened to switch keyboard layout with alt+left shift.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes I have.

Open the preferences dialogue and type in "keys" in the search field. in the keys-preferences dialogue type in "ctrl+alt+q"  (= <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> -> @-symbol on german keyboards). In my case it was bound to the command "Show Revision Graph" from the subversive plugin. Click on the command and delete the binding. confirm it by clicking ok, your @ should work again.

Comment: Hi there, thx for your second answer, but you must have misunderstood. Your first answer already solved the problem ;-)

Comment: You might need to restart Eclipse to take the key unbind fully into effect.

Comment: For me this binding was stolen by the SonarQube plugin. Would have taken me ages and a lot of frustration to find this!

Answer (score 0):

got the same problem -> found a solution

under preferences (window/preferences) navigate to the key bindings (general/keys) type "ctrl+alt+q" inside the search box -> delete the binding or bind the action to an other key-combination.

Comment: @Alex_M: Please delete this duplicate answer!